# ResourceWarning: subprocess 47013 is still running Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name=5 mode='rb' closefd=True>

Tags: python, linux

I got trouble to face the error, could you help me?.
Please take a look at my code!

code in file tools.py

```
from action import Action
import typer
from rich.table import Table
from rich.console import Console
from model import Command
from shell import Shell
import os

db=Action("localhost","root","","db_cmd")

sh=Shell()
console=Console()
app=typer.Typer()

@app.command(short_help="Untuk melihat data")
def show():
    lists=db.show_data()
    # print(lists)
    console.print("[bold magenta]command alias[/bold magenta]!","️")

    # print(lists)
    table=Table(show_header=True, header_style="bold blue")
    table.add_column("No", style="dim", width=6, justify="center")
    table.add_column("command", min_width=20, justify="center")
    table.add_column("isi command", min_width=12, justify="center")
    table.add_column("deskripsi", min_width=12, justify="center")
    if len(lists) > 0 :
        for i, list in enumerate(lists, start=1):
            table.add_row(str(i), list.cmd, list.isi_cmd, list.deskripsi)
    else:
        table.add_row("-","-","-","-")
    console.print(table)


@app.command(short_help="Untuk menambahkan data")
def add(cmd:str=None, isi_cmd:str=None, deskripsi:str=None):
    typer.echo(f"Menambahkan command {cmd}")
    shell=sh.shellName()


@app.command(short_help="Untuk menghapus data")
def delete(position):
    cmd=db.cmd(int(position)-1)
    typer.echo(f"deleting command {cmd}")
    db.delete_data(int(position)-1) 
    show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app()
```

code in file shell.py

```
import os
import subprocess
import signal

class Shell:
    def add(self, cmd, isi_cmd, shell):
        if shell == "zsh":
            os.system(f"printf 'alias {cmd}=\"{isi_cmd}\"\n' >> /home/$USER/.zshrc")
        elif shell == "bash":
            os.system(f"printf 'alias {cmd}=\"{isi_cmd}\"\n' >> /home/$USER/.bashrc")
        elif shell == "fish":
            os.system(f"printf 'alias {cmd}=\"{isi_cmd}\"\n' >> /home/$USER/.fzf.bash")

    def delete(self):
        pass

    def shellName(self):
        result=subprocess.Popen("echo $SHELL", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        arr=str(result.stdout.read()).split("/")
        shell=arr[3].replace("\\n'","")
        return shell

 shell=Shell()
 print(shell.shellName())
```

When I run the file named shell.py and called the method sh.shellName(), the program was running well

```
$python3 shell.py
zsh
```

But when I run the file named tools.py, and sh.shellName() method, it show me error like this

```
$python3 tools.py add --cmd="ls" --isi-cmd="ls -lah" --deskripsi="Untuk melihat isi file beserta ukurannya"
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x7fa7c6d36550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 946, in __del__
    _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: subprocess 48516 is still running
Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name=4 mode='rb' closefd=True>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fajar/Documents/python/tools_alias_cmd/shell.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(shell.shellName())
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=4>
zsh
Menambahkan command ls
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x7fa7c6d36550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 946, in __del__
    _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: subprocess 48517 is still running
Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name=5 mode='rb' closefd=True>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools.py", line 38, in add
    shell=sh.shellName()
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=5>
```

I'v been searching all the solutions on google, youtube, and  forum, but I got nothing, it doesn't work for my problems. Thanks